# if statement (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I was unable to figure out, what was causing `10` that keeps to be displayed red. Other numbers are displaying like it should, but only on number `10` if statement fails to compare proper value.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function(){

    var compare = $(this).text()

        if( compare == 'null' ) {
             $(this).text('No rating found').parent('tr').addClass("table-danger");
        }
          else if ( compare <= '5' ) { //Number 10 keeps comparing whit this statement       
                        $(this).parent('tr').addClass("table-danger");    
          }
          else if ( compare > '5' &&  compare < '7' ) {       
                        $(this).parent('tr').addClass("table-info");    
          }
           else if ( compare >= '7' ) {       
                        $(this).parent('tr').addClass("table-success");    
          }
     });
});
```

Something is wrong whit first `else if` statement. And number `10` should be green `("table-success")`

> **Live Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/gah1m33d/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing 10 [a number] with a string value of 5. Try:

```
else if ( parseInt(compare) <= 5 )
```

Comment: problem solved, but how is that other numbers are displayed ok?

Comment: '10' starts with '1' and therefore < '5'.